# docker-compose.yml: Error while specifying a tmpfs volume

Tags: docker, docker-compose

For following docker run command,

```
docker run --rm -itd --privileged --cap-add=SYS_PTRACE --cap-add=SYS_ADMIN -v /dev/shm --tmpfs /dev/shm:rw,nosuid,nodev,exec centos:7
```

I would like to run it via `docker-compose up`

Here is docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
services:
  centos-testing:
    image: centos:7
    privileged: true
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    ulimits:
      nproc: 655353
      nofile:
        soft: 20000
        hard: 40000
    cap_add:
        - SYS_PTRACE
        - SYS_ADMIN
    volumes:
      - type: tmpfs
        source: /dev/shm
        target: /dev/shm:rw,nosuid,nodev,exec
    networks:
      - testnet
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "2"
          memory: 50M
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure

networks:
  testnet:
```

I am getting the following error when i run `docker-compose up`

```
ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
services.centos-testing.volumes contains an invalid type, it should be a string
```

How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 5):

You're using docker-compose file version 3, and you need version 3.6 if you want to use `-type: tmpfs` specifying target.

Just try replacing `version: "3"` by `version: "3.6"`

More information in:
[Docker compose info to use tmpfs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#tmpfs)

Comment: And what if I have to stick to compose version 3? From the docs it looks like we can't mount tmpfs in compose versions 3-3.5 in swarm?

Comment: If you want to use docker compose file syntax version 3, you can use tmpfs but you've to do this: first, mount tmpfs (before launching docker-compose), then, share volume. 
If you want to have tmpfs only inside, you need to create it in Dockerfile - docker-compose build